# Are these two definitions of cofibration the same?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, definition, homotopy-theory, cofibrations

$\newcommand{\cgh}{\mathsf{CGHaus}}$I'm reading through Goerss/Jardine's simplicial homotopy theory, and came across the word 'cofibration' for the first time. I tried to do some reading from other sources, but Goerss/Jardine seem to be using an ostensibly 'different' notion of cofibration to the rest of the world. I use notation standard to simplicial sets throughout.

I'll be specific now. Let $\cgh$ be the category of compactly generated Hausdorff spaces. The authors were discussing the 'closed model structure' of $\cgh$, wherein a *fibration* is defined to be a Serre fibration:

> A (Serre) fibration is a map $f\in\cgh(U,V)$ such that for all integer $n>0$ and all $0\le k\le n$, $f$ has the right lifting property against the inclusion $|\Lambda^n_k|\hookrightarrow|\Delta^n|$.

I'm fairly sure this definition is equivalent to the (seemingly) more standard definition of the same in terms of lifting against $|\Delta^n|\hookrightarrow|\Delta^n|\times|\Delta^1|$.

They define:

> A *cofibration* $i\in\cgh(U,V)$ is a map that has the left lifting property against all trivial fibrations.

A 'trivial' fibration is a fibration that is also a weak homotopy equivalence. This definition seems very removed from the definitions of the same on nLab: I could hardly even parse those!

My first question:

- Is the Goerss-Jardine definition equivalent to the standard meaning of cofibration (whatever that is?)?

On another note, they proved (for simplicial fibrations) that a map is a trivial fibration iff. it has the right lifting property against all inclusions $\partial\Delta^n\hookrightarrow\Delta^n,n\ge0$. According to nLab, this holds in the topological world - a map is a Serre fibration iff. it has the lifting property against the inclusions $S^{n-1}\hookrightarrow D^n,n\ge0$.

- Is there a similar characterisation of the trivial cofibrations? (in either the 'standard' sense or in the sense of Goerss-Jardine?)

Comment: Are you familiar with model categories generally?

Comment: @Randall No, my first encounter with them has been this page of Goerss-Jardine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes.

The general setup is as follows: in order to do homotopy theory, the basic framework is a *model category* (and we can focus on the two examples of simplicial sets and an appropriate category of topological spaces, like $\mathsf{CGHaus}$). To define a model category, we need three classes of maps:

- cofibrations (which you can think of as "nice inclusions")
- fibrations ("nice surjections")
- weak equivalences

As you say, the "trivial fibrations" are the maps that are both fibrations and weak equivalences, and similarly for the trivial cofibrations.

The weak equivalences are the maps we want to invert, and we typically know those ahead of time: they are weak homotopy equivalences in our two examples. However we define the other two, we need the cofibrations to have the left lifting property with respect to trivial fibrations, and we need the fibrations to have the right lifting property with respect to trivial cofibrations.

Of the other two, sometimes it's easier to define cofibrations, sometimes fibrations. For simplicial sets, it is easiest to define cofibrations — they're just inclusions. For topological spaces, it is easiest to first define some maps that you want to be trivial cofibrations (the inclusions  $i_0: D^n \to D^n \times I$) and then define the fibrations in terms of a lifting property with respect to those, and then define the cofibrations in terms of a lifting property with respect to the trivial fibrations. You can choose different families for these "generating cofibrations," and the ones that Goerss and Jardine use are just as good as $D^n \to D^n \times I$. With some work, you can then say that certain families of maps, like the inclusions of subcomplexes into CW complexes, are cofibrations. I don't know how easy it is to give a self-contained description of all cofibrations, though. (By "self-contained," I mean without reference to the fibrations.)

(To make the "generating cofibration" approach work, you should also define some maps that you know that you want to be cofibrations. A good choice is the family $S^{n-1} \to D^n$, also known as $|\partial \Delta^n| \to |\Delta^n|$. See Lemma 9.4 in Goerss-Jardine, for example.)

Comment: And must we define fibrations and cofibrations relative to each other in this way because of abstract nonsense involving model categories (i.e. that is the convenient, ‘correct’ way)?

Comment: You don't have to define them this way, but it tends to be really awkward to define each class of morphisms separately. For simplicial sets, the cofibrations are the inclusions, and that's fine, but it's hard to give a nice description of the fibrations. For topological spaces, the Hurewicz fibrations are not so hard to describe, but it's hard to give a nice description of the complete class of cofibrations.

Comment: Right, thanks. Does it then follow from the lifting definition that the trivial cofibrations of Kan complexes are precisely the anodyne extensions (between Kan complexes)?

Comment: It seems that way, given the proof on p. 68: any trivial cofibration $i$ seems to be a retract of an anodyne extension, and hence is anodyne itself. The nLab people say (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/anodyne+morphism) that when the small object argument applies (and it does in simplicial sets), then the anodyne morphisms are those with the left lifting property with respect to all fibrations, and hence they are the trivial cofibrations.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Do you know how to show Goerss-Jardine’s definition of Serre fibration is equivalent to the usual one (right lifting property against inclusions $I^n\times\{0\}\hookrightarrow I^n\times I$)? The usual way to prove such things is via taking suitable coproducts and pushouts, CW-complex style, but it’s not obvious to me how to build a horn in this way (or visa versa)

Comment: One approach is that of "cofibrantly generated model categories," which is what my post starts to describe. That should provide the structure to verify that the various definitions match up, although it may be difficult to work out all of the details. Hovey's book "Model Categories" is one resource.